# Why Yen grew stronger after North Korea's H-bomb threat?

Tags: currency, international-economics, money, currency-exchange

> Financial markets have had only a muted reaction to the dispute in
>   recent months, but on Friday assets regarded as havens for investors
>   jumped immediately after the news of North Korea’s latest H-bomb
>   threat. The Japanese yen firmed as much as 0.5 per cent to ¥111.96 per
>   dollar. Gold was also 0.5 per cent stronger at $1,297.09 per ounce.

(Source: [Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/199a98be-9ee0-11e7-8cd4-932067fbf946))

I thought Yen would grow weaker, but on the contrary it grew stronger, why?

Comment: Because it's considered a safe haven. See [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17810/why-is-jpy-considered-a-safe-currency).

Comment: Consider also that the NK saber-rattling increases the likelihood of the US military spending additional money in Japan.

Comment: Notice that the flagging as duplicate is to make you aware of such other question, and edit your question making clear why yours might not be a duplicate (if so).